# Enable AMD-virtualization

Tags: virtualization, bios, hyperthreading

Before 3 weeks maybe, i faced a problem in launching WP emulator. After troubleshooting, i found that visualization option in my Laptop is not running successfully.

Laptop spec. (Acer 4253):
CPU: AMD E-350, Zacate 40nm Technology
OS: Operating System,   Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
RAM: 4.00GB DDR3 @ 532MHz

I have downloaded [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy/download) to check visualization info, since nothing relate to visualization is appear in bios settings, and i found that "Hyper-threading" is not supported!, any help?

[image]

Comment: hyprethreading is a proprietary intel technology to pretend that there are multiple cores inside one core. I don't think it makes a difference for virtualization. there is comprehensive info on checks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @comprehensible hyperthreading does help in virtualization, according to VMWare. Which was to be expected, I don't see a reason why hyperthreading wouldn't bring performance benefits. check this out: http://blogs.vmware.com/apps/2015/09/the-debate-about-disabling-hyperthreading-in-virtualized-exchange-server-is-over.html

Answer (score 0):

Hyperthreading is only an Intel technology, AMD doesn't have hperthreading on any of it's processors evem the AMD FX generation.

Hyper-threading (officially called Hyper-Threading Technology or HT Technology, and abbreviated as HTT or HT) is Intel's proprietary simultaneous multithreading (SMT) implementation used to improve parallelization of computations.

For Virtualizaton, you have written it ok in the title, but you wrote visualization wrong every time... processors dont have visualization.:)

Everything on your WP configuration looks ok, you shouldn't worry what the amd parameters are because they are just fine... you have to just configure and run the program same as for any amd processor, which is probably the same with intel, programs have almost zero configuration differences between the two.